# How many days old process history we can see in Tridion workflow management tab

Tags: 2013, workflow, processhistory

How many days old process history we can see in Tridion workflow management  tab as shown in below diagram[image]

Can somebody point me to some documentation for this.

Answer (score 4):

By default Tridion keeps all Workflow process history in its database, so you will have access to all processes created since the "beginning of times".

You can purge all processes which occurred before a certain date using the Remove-TcmProcessHistories PowerShell command. 
[See Documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3A6C6B63-8B2A-4F37-B588-C72CA70B7A83).

Comment: In older versions of Tridion you would use the "Purge tool" to purge workflow process history.